# Migrating data from sql server to postgres generated: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: java, sql-server, postgresql

I'm trying to migrate my current SQL server (2017) to postgres (14.5) using migration toolkit (version 55).

I set up he configuration file as follows:

```
SRC_DB_URL=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:55555/EFDemoDB;integratedSecurity=true;
SRC_DB_USER=
SRC_DB_PASSWORD=
TARGET_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:55555/EFDemoDB
TARGET_DB_USER=postgres
TARGET_DB_PASSWORD=55555
```

And ran the migration tool using the following command line:

```
.\runMTK.bat  -sourcedbtype sqlserver -targetdbtype postgresql guest
```

The migration tool stared executing and successfully:

1. connected to the SRC DB
2. connected to the TARGET DB
3. Created the schema on the TARGET DB (tables, indexes and FK)

**And here comes the funny part:**

4. The Data loader started to work and immediately generated this error:

```
com.edb.MTKException: MTK-11009: Error Connecting Database "SQL Server"
DB-08S01: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

Please note: it doesn't matter if I use SQL authentication or windows authentication against SQL Server, I get the same results!

Here is the full log file of the migration

```
2022-09-01 23:58:18 Running EnterpriseDB Migration Toolkit (Build 55.2.3) ...

2022-09-01 23:58:18 Source database connectivity info...

2022-09-01 23:58:18 conn=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:*****/EFDemoDB;integratedSecurity=true;

2022-09-01 23:58:18 user =

2022-09-01 23:58:18 password=******

2022-09-01 23:58:18 Connecting with source SQL Server database server...

2022-09-01 23:58:18 Connected to Microsoft SQL Server, version '14.00.3445'

2022-09-01 23:58:18 Importing sql server schema guest...

2022-09-01 23:58:18 Getting Table Definitions

2022-09-01 23:58:19 Creating Tables...

2022-09-01 23:58:19 Creating Table: guest.addresses

2022-09-01 23:58:19 Creating Table: guest.emailaddresses

2022-09-01 23:58:19 Creating Table: guest.people

**2022-09-01 23:58:19 Created 3 tables.**

2022-09-01 23:58:19 Initializing Data Loader 1...

**2022-09-01 23:58:19 Data loader task failed to initialize. Reason: MTK-11009: Error Connecting Database "SQL Server"
DB-08S01: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed**

**2022-09-01 23:58:19 MTK-11009: Error Connecting Database "SQL Server"
DB-08S01: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed**

2022-09-01 23:58:19 Stack Trace:
com.edb.MTKException: MTK-11009: Error Connecting Database "SQL Server"
DB-08S01: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at com.edb.common.MTKFactory.createMTKConnection(MTKFactory.java:277) ~[edb-migrationtoolkit.jar:?]
    at com.edb.MigrationToolkit.createNewSourceConnection(MigrationToolkit.java:7242) ~[edb-migrationtoolkit.jar:?]
    at com.edb.DataLoader.initialize(DataLoader.java:287) ~[edb-migrationtoolkit.jar:?]
    at com.edb.DataLoader.<init>(DataLoader.java:225) ~[edb-migrationtoolkit.jar:?]
    at com.edb.MigrationToolkit.copyTables(MigrationToolkit.java:5073) ~[edb-migrationtoolkit.jar:?]
    at com.edb.MigrationToolkit.copyTables(MigrationToolkit.java:4831) ~[edb-migrationtoolkit.jar:?]
    at com.edb.MigrationToolkit.importSchema(MigrationToolkit.java:4383) ~[edb-migrationtoolkit.jar:?]
    at com.edb.MigrationToolkit.main(MigrationToolkit.java:2166) [edb-migrationtoolkit.jar:?]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2481) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:632) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at com.edb.common.JTDSConnection.<init>(JTDSConnection.java:50) ~[edb-migrationtoolkit.jar:?]
    at com.edb.common.MTKFactory.createMTKConnection(MTKFactory.java:274) ~[edb-migrationtoolkit.jar:?]
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.readPacket(SharedSocket.java:850) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.getNetPacket(SharedSocket.java:731) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.getPacket(ResponseStream.java:477) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.read(ResponseStream.java:114) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2368) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:632) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at com.edb.common.JTDSConnection.<init>(JTDSConnection.java:50) ~[edb-migrationtoolkit.jar:?]
    at com.edb.common.MTKFactory.createMTKConnection(MTKFactory.java:274) ~[edb-migrationtoolkit.jar:?]
    ... 7 more
2022-09-01 23:58:19 

2022-09-01 23:58:19 One or more schema objects could not be imported during the migration process. Please review the migration output for more details.

2022-09-01 23:58:19 Total Elapsed Migration Time (sec): 1.122
```

Comment: The jTDS driver is horribly outdated. You should be using the Microsoft JDBC driver instead.

Comment: Have you resolve this issue? I have the same problem...

Comment: SQL server may listen to more than one port!
Run
USE MASTER
GO
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on'
GO
And try to take the other port. 
This worked for me.